# system cannot be resolved to a variable or is not a fiel

Tags: android

```
private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

   return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

}
```

I am getting an error saying syntax error in token "("; is expected

Comment: something like this `(Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0)` maybe

Comment: The code looks OK. I think the error is in a different line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for was moved to Global.

Try changing it to this:

```
return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

}
```